# How to set an array to another array after changing the source array in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an http method that returns an array of models. I used another api method in the first method's pipe like this:

```
  initModel() {
this.currentService
  .organizationsDownloadAllOrganizationDocuments({
    OrganizationId: this.organizationId,
  })
  .pipe(
    map((items) => {
      items.forEach((item) => {
        this.currentService
          .organizationsOrganizationDocumentLink({
            Input: item.image,
          })
          .subscribe((image) => {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(image);
            reader.onloadend = function () {
              item.image = reader.result.toString();
            };
          });
      });
      return items;
    }),
    tap((items) => {
      this.documentsModel = Object.assign([], items);
      console.log('docModel', this.documentsModel);
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

}

I want to change the item's images and set all the new array to 'documentModel'. all the fields works well except 'description'.The returned data from api is like this and it's corrent:

```
0: {image: "MS85ZWM4ODQ5Mi1lYTFiLTQ5NDUtYmQ0OC0zYTg4NzM4MzJkMTY=", organizationDocument: 
    1, status: 3,…}
     description: "wrwerte"
     image: "MS85ZWM4ODQ5Mi1lYTFiLTQ5NDUtYmQ0OC0zYTg4NzM4MzJkMTY="
     organizationDocument: 1
     status: 3
  1: {image: "MS9jNjE0ZDI3NC1kMzdhLTRmYWMtOTE2MS0wNWEzZDJjNWM4NDQ=", 
   organizationDocument: 2, status: 3,…}
   description: "erterte"
   image: "MS9jNjE0ZDI3NC1kMzdhLTRmYWMtOTE2MS0wNWEzZDJjNWM4NDQ="
   organizationDocument: 2
   status: 3
```

but the final result of 'documentModel' is like this:

```
   0:
   description: "jjkkkkkkkkkkkk"
   image: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAA
   organizationDocument: 1
   status: 3
   [[Prototype]]: Object
 1:
 description: "jjkkkkkkkkkkkk"
 image: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAA
 organizationDocument: 2
 status: 3
```

all of the fields are okay but the description from all the items are the same.(this description is for the last item of array that is repeated for all the items). I defined the 'documentModel' globally before constructor. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to leverage rxjs' capabilities in order to simplify the things a bit.

```
initModel() {
  this.currentService
    .organizationsDownloadAllOrganizationDocuments({
      OrganizationId: this.organizationId,
    })
    .pipe(
      switchMap((organizations) =>
        forkJoin(this.getImages(organizations)).pipe(
          map((images) => [organizations, images])
        )
      ),
      map(([organizations, images]) =>
        organizations.map((org, index) => ({
          ...org,
          image: images[index],
        }))
      )
    )
    .subscribe((organizations) => {
      this.documentsModel = organizations;
    });
}

private getImages(organizations: any[]): Observable<any>[] {
  return organizations.map((org) =>
    this.currentService
      .organizationsOrganizationDocumentLink({
        Input: org.image,
      })
      .pipe(
        switchMap(
          (image) =>
            new Observable((subscriber) => {
              const reader = new FileReader();
              reader.readAsDataURL(image);
              reader.onloadend = function () {
                subscriber.next(reader.result?.toString());
                subscriber.complete();
              };
            })
        )
      )
  );
}
```

I don't think it's elegant to have an empty `subscribe()` call like that. All of this must have a *purpose*.

Comment: I used this code but it returns the model like in the question. It returns all descriptions the same.

Comment: Then check what comes back from the server, and check what else happens with the data after you fetch it. Insert a `console.log(this.documentsModel);` in the subscribe handler to see if the data is correct after fetching.

Comment: yes. the data that comes from the server is correct as I mentioned in the question. something happens to it when I'm trying to change the 'image' field.

Comment: Are you sure you are using this exact code that I included in my answer? This does not touch on the description property. Must be something else that you do some place else that is modifying the description. How do you render it in your template?

Comment: Yes,I copied and pasted your code without changes. I just create a loop using *ngFor in documentModel and show the items. I don't change description anywhere.

Comment: Did you insert the log in the `subscribe` handler, just after the line on which we assign `this.documentsModel = organizations;`? Log either one of them after the assignment and check the content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246486/discussion-between-octavian-mrculescu-and-niki-tmb).